# insert data row after row to datagridview upon pressed button? vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How can I insert data row after row to DataGridView from database, from which the criteria is based on the name of a pressed button?

See my code below:

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim selmenu As String = txtmenus.Text
    Try
        Dim btn1 As Button = CType(sender, Button)
        Dim str As String = btn1.Text.Trim()
        Dim str1 As Integer = Val(btn1.Name.Trim())

        txtmenus.Text = Val(str1.ToString())
        cmbGroup.Enabled = True
        MessageBox.Show("ID: " & str1)
        DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
        'If cmbBillType.Text = "Takeaway" Or cmbBillType.Text = "Express Billing" Or cmbBillType.Text = "Home Delivery" Then
        con = New OleDbConnection(cs)
        con.Open()
        cmd = con.CreateCommand()
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ItemID,Dishname, Rate from Dish,Category where Category.Categoryname=Dish.Category and ItemID=@d2"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", Val(txtmenus.Text))
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()


        If rdr.Read() Then
            For Each r As DataGridViewRow In Me.DataGridView1.Rows
                con = New OleDbConnection(cs)
                con.Open()
                cmd = con.CreateCommand()
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ItemID,Dishname, Rate from Dish,Category where Category.Categoryname=Dish.Category and ItemID=@d2"
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", Val(txtmenus.Text))
                If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 Then

                    r.Cells(0).Value = rdr(0)
                    r.Cells(1).Value = rdr(1)
                    r.Cells(2).Value = rdr(2)
                    r.Cells(3).Value = 1
                    r.Cells(4).Value = r.Cells(2).Value * r.Cells(3).Value
                    Exit Sub

                End If
            Next
        End If

        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(rdr(0), rdr(1), rdr(2))
        DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(3).Value = 1
        DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(4).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(2).Value * DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(3).Value
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.[Error])
    End Try
End Sub
```